# Change Excel formula to total only visible cells

Tags: excel, worksheet-function, subtotal

I'm using the following formula to create a total of unique values

> =SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH(C4:C9,C4:C9,0),MATCH(C4:C9,C4:C9,0))>0,1))

However, I'm now using an autofilter, so I now need it to sum only the visible rows. I've read that I need to use SUBTOTAL instead of SUM, but I'm not sure how to change the formula above correcly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Use `=SUBTOTAL(9,C4:C9)`, where 9 is the function number of `sum` ( if you're typing this into the sheet, the intellisense dialog will pop up and you can select it without having to remember the function number).</strike>

I don't remember where it is in 2003, but I know that in 2007 or later, if your filtered column has a header, select the cells (including the header), and click the subtotal box on the `Data` tab.

Edit:  I think you are looking for a `COUNTIF` instead: `=COUNTIF(C4:C9,"=FREQUENCY(etc.)>0")`.  You may need an array formula with that if you are using `MATCH`.

Comment: Thanks jonsca, but I had tried that approach =SUBTOTAL(9, IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH(C4:C9,C4:C9,0),MATCH(C4:C9,C4:C9,0))>0,1))

Comment: @Mitch Yes, the subtotal must be used with one of those functions listed.  Why do you need the `match` formula in there?  Just click on the label row and select which elements you want visible.

Comment: I think the problem is that simply replacing =SUM with =SUBTOTAL(9, is ok when you have a range specified ie =(SUBTOTAL(9, C4:C9), but not when it contains a formula ie =SUBTOTAL(9, IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH(C4:C9,C4:C9,0),MATCH(C4:C9,C4:C9,0))>0,1)). Maybe it needs to be totally refactored to use SUBTOTAL?

Comment: @Mitch I think I see what you are saying.  I'm not sure if there's a shorthand way to do it, but you could say if the statement is true, put a 1 in the adjacent cell and then sum those adjacent cells using subtotal.